# PHP Mail function From line in Header gets overwritten

Tags: php, html-email

I have the following snippet of code from y mail script:

```
$headers = 'Content-type:text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \r\n';
$headers .= 'From: webmaster@somewhere.com' . "\r\n";
mail($row2['data'],"Some Company Email Confirmation ",$msg,$headers );
```

For some odd reason, the email sends successful but doesnt pickup the from field im passing to the header variable or atleast it doesnt show  up the mail message header as being from the address i specified..it picks up the server address. What am i missing here?

Thanks all

Comment: Have you tried to change \r\n to "\r\n" at the first line? You did it at the second line.

Comment: @bub That worked! Thanks a million....